# Inner Join de dos tablas con los campos con el mismo nombre

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Hola estoy intentando hacer un INNER JOIN entre dos tablas las cuales tienen un campo con el mismo nombre.

La consulta que estoy realizando es la siguiente:

```
SELECT contactos.codigo, contactos.nombre, contactos.fecha_nac, 
       contactos.paciente_asociado, contactos.vinculo, contactos.otros, 
       contactos.tlf, contactos.dni, contactos.baja, pacientes.nombre 
FROM contactos 
INNER JOIN pacientes ON paciente_asociado = historia
```

Paciente asociado es la historia del paciente de la tabla pacientes, pero yo quiero que me muestre el nombre del paciente no la historia a ver si alguien puede echarme una mano.

Muchas gracias

Comment: no alcanzo a entender qué problema estás teniendo...

Comment: si quieres diferenciar de donde viene la tabla, puedes usar un `as` para personalizar el nombre de la columna, pero como tal no veo el problema... no sabemos que datos te devuelve esa consulta, cual es la estructura de las tablas... necesitaríamos más información para poder ayudarte, el nombre de la pregunta no concuerda con lo que dices que está mal

Comment: Como relacionas contactos con pacientes?

Comment: Aparte de tener que nombrar con un alias ambas tablas, veo que el inner join no está bien definido ya que tendrías que asociar las tablas con los ids correspondientes

Comment: creo que el problema no es que se llamen igual, el problema son tus datos por que no colocas tus tablas, mas información para que se pueda entender el problema

Answer (score 0):

Tendrias que añadir un alias a la tabla

```
INNER JOIN pacientes pa ON contactos.paciente_asociado = pa.historia**
```

Comment: no es necesario asignar el `alias` bien puede hacer `contactos.paciente_asociado = pacientes.historia`